# New Kubernetes with Weave cluster... All ports except 80 blocked

Tags: iptables, docker, kubernetes, weave

I have recently set up Kubernetes 1.12.1 with Weave (1 master and 2 hosts on bare metal Ubuntu VMs). I'm trying to make outbound connections from pods to send email (SMTP), but it appears that all ports except 80 are blocked (confirmed using nc from shell inside containers). However, I have not applied a Network Policy. The ports are not blocked from the Kubernetes hosts.

What could be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking the results of `iptables -S`. Since this is Kubernetes, firewall rules will be managed as well.

Since your question is lacking in terms of details:

- do you want to connect to SMTP outside of the cluster? Then nothing should be blocked.
- do you want to connect to SMTP running in a pod in the cluster? Then it needs to be exposed as a service.